# Checking if my default variable is None throws a method not found error

Tags: rust

I have my own implementation of queues (there might be some better crate in Rust, it's irrelevant, I'm trying to learn for now). It looks like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Queue<T: Clone> {
    queue: Vec<T>,
}
```

I am trying to use it as an argument in a different module, but I'm having some issues wrapping my head around Rust's default arguments. My module looks like this:

```
impl TestHandler {
    pub async fn new<I>(
        config: Config,
        service_queue: I,
    ) -> Result<Self, TestError> where
        I: Into<Option<Queue<isize>>>,
    {
        ...

        if service_queue.is_none() {
            let mut service_queue: Queue<isize> = crate::queue![];
        }

        let mut handler = Self {
            ...
            service_queue,
        };

        Ok(handler)
    }

...
```

The compiler complains that:

```
   |
47 |         if service_queue.is_none() {
   |                          ^^^^^^^ method not found in `I`
```

I was hoping that `Option` would mean exactly this. Namely that I can pass a None if I so wish. I'm not sure what `Into` does, I just know that without it, it won't work.

What is the correct way for me to define my custom module as an optional argument in the Handler's constructor, and check if the value was given or not?

Comment: There's a lot of code missing here so it's hard to determine what exactly you need to change. However, at first glance, your attempted `if` block declares a new variable and does nothing with it. More likely, you are probably looking for [`.unwrap_or_else()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else), but first you have to `.into()` to convert the argument to an `Option`. Without seeing the declaration of `TestHandler`, this is just a guess.

Comment: I tried including what I believed to be relevant information only. `TestHandler` is a struct that among others contains a `service_queue: Queue<isize>`. So if this `service_queue` is given during construction, then it will be used.Otherwise a new empty `service_queue` will be created and used instead. But the `.is_none()` is not working. I'll try and understand this better and then edit my question.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you can't make `service_queue` in the function just a non-generic `Option<Queue<isize>>`. The `Into` trait doesn't really help anything here.

Comment: that was my first understanding based on what I know. But if I don't put it then I get `Expected trait, found enum 'Option'`

Comment: Can you show that code? Note that you don't need a generic argument here, just `service_queue: Option<Queue<isize>>`. No `<I>` required here.

Comment: Which code specifically? It's just the part of the code seen above, but without the `Input`. I made a generic argument because I saw it used by a few open source projects. I'm studying. So I'm looking more into understanding why when I do it, things go south.

Comment: Usually you don't accept `Into` as arguments except in a few cases, where you specifically want to allow different types of values to be passed, that can be converted to a given type. That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues here.  First, you don't really need the generic argument `I` at all.  Just accept the `Option`:

```
    pub async fn new(
        config: Config,
        service_queue: Option<Queue<isize>>,
    ) -> Result<Self, TestError>
```

That solves the issue with `is_none()` but your `if` block is faulty -- it declares a new variable that's not used, but it appears to *intend* to provide a default value for the argument.  That's easily done with [`Option::unwrap_or_else()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else), without an `if` block at all:

```
let service_queue = service_queue.unwrap_or_else(|| crate::queue![]);
```

This is a more succinct way to write:

```
let service_queue = match service_queue {
    Some(v) => v,
    None => crate::queue![],
};
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why is `InteliJ` outlining that generic argument and complaining that `Expected trait, found enum 'Option'` if I remove `Into`? For some reason it forces me to use `into` when I never intended to, and as it seems I shouldn't.

Comment: @dearn44 Because you use generic arguments to deal with any number of possible types provided by the caller. The only useful way to constrain those kinds of types is by trait or lifetime. `Into` is a trait, so that works -- but `Option` is an enum, so using it as a bound for a generic type makes no sense.

Comment: I need to read your last comment a few times until I understand it, but thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @dearn44 If you want to accept "an `Option` of a type that implements a trait" you'd express that differently, like `fn example<T>(foo: Option<T>) where T: SomeTrait { ... }`. Notice how the trait is the bound, not `Option`, but we can _use_ the generic type with other generic types like `Option`.